# konvajs doubled canvas (Buffered Canvas)

Tags: konvajs

Hello Stack Overflow Community!

This platform had often answers for my problem in all my years as programmer. Now I finally came to this point where I cannot find anything in google and ask it here. ow

I'm using konvajs in my project and created 4 layers. Everything runs very fine, but now I want to export the whole stage as an image. My problem on this point is, that it is exporting the image (DataURL) in 3840x2160 instead of 1920x1080.

Im setting the stage.size({width:1920,height:1080}).

What is the reason konvajs is doing this? Has it same purpose like MSAA technique? Can I export image, with 1920x1080? Why are my canvas tags 2x resolution?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElfgH.png)

Thank you!

Comment: How do you export? Calling toDataURL manually on canvas elements?

Comment: stage.toDataURL()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stage.toDataURL()` should give you an image of the same size as the stage 1920x1080.

But in the DOM Konva is using larger canvas size for HDPI devices support (like retina display) so your canvas still looks good. The canvas is larger but it is scaled back to the original stage size.

Comment: yes I had an head break..
Of course toDataURL is giving (like you've said) the correct output.
The problem was: I had some transformations which I have of course to reset. So my solution was: 1) clone the stage 2) transform to wished values 3) use toDataURL from this resetted clone 4) destroy this clone. I will mark your solution as correct